# Intent for official SE Android app?

Tags: feature-request, android

Does the official SE Android app export intents? If not, can they be added?

My app, for example, allows users to click on many UI elements to let them see the original question, users profile, site home and tags page; now it opens them in the device browser, but it would be really good if it could check for official app's intents and use them when available.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange app can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en)

It's features are listed as:

```
Version 1.0.60 can access:
Identity
find accounts on the device
Photos/Media/Files
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
read the contents of your USB storage
Other
receive data from Internet
prevent device from sleeping
read Google service configuration
full network access
control vibration
view network connections
```

So Intents aren't supported yet, but I believe they are to be implemented in a version update soon.

For the record: [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: actually...the SE app export A LOT of intents, they are just undocumented. I was hoping for an official answer from its developer, here, instead of having to unpack the app and look at its manifest.